macos socket server does not respond when the screen goes off
I have a mac (macOS 14.5, Python 3.10) running a python socket server.
I have an ubuntu 22.04 PC that kicks off a python socket client and connects to the server no problem over my local network.

When the mac screen is on, the server responds just fine.

If I wait long enough, the mac screen eventually goes black, and the server stops responding. (Not sure if this called "hibernation" or not)

If I tap the touchpad on the laptop, the screen comes on, the server starts responding again, no problem. In other words:



I don't have to log in for it work okay.
I don't have to restart the server for it work okay.


If I wait for the mac to go black, I start the client on ubuntu (no response), wait 10s, and THEN tap the touchpad, the moment the mac screen turns on, the server starts responding, no problem. This implies that the ethernet driver or the socket on the mac is buffering the incoming command. Not sure if this is relevant.

What can I do to get the Mac to respond at all times?
Related question: do I need to use a service on the Mac?

Look for "Prevent automatic sleeping when the display is off" in Settings -> Energy Saver.
